# Forcing the window to redraw

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using (`devexpressmvvm` nuget package) for a two language application.
I used the `ResourceManager` to make the change of the used language resource file.
and added two buttons to change the language (one for English, the other for Arabic).
i want to update all values in the Window after changing the language resource file.

**Resource Manager**

```
public static ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("SmartLawyer.Resources.Lang.Ar", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

**the two commands**

```
public void En()
{
    rm = new ResourceManager("SmartLawyer.Resources.Lang.En", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    FlowDirection = "LeftToRight";
}

public void Ar()
{
    rm = new ResourceManager("SmartLawyer.Resources.Lang.Ar", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    FlowDirection = "RightToLeft";
}
```

**UI Element**

```
<TextBlock Text="{conv:NameToValue Name=AddButton}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

**Converter namespace**

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:SmartLawyer.Converters"
```

**Converter**

```
class NameToValue : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public object Name { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value != "")
            return VMMainWindow.rm.GetString((String)value);
        return "";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Name != null && Name != "")
            return VMMainWindow.rm.GetString((String)Name);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add binding for each string in memory, and add an `event` for language changing. When the selected language changed, you change the bind values for all bindings you store beforehand. No need to redraw the window.

Comment: The comment above is correct. WPF / UWP doesn't have the concept of redrawing like WinForms does. Drawing is handled by the framework and is automatic.  It will update when it detects changes and binding is the most popular way of doing this although other techniques can be used depending on your needs.  In other words, if you have to manage the drawing it may be code smell it was designed wrong. There are low level api's for working with it and using things like FLUENT API gives you a clean and usable way of accessing those but they still aren't needed at the top.

Comment: If it's about dynamic localization, you can use the WPF Localization Extensions, for example (available on NuGet & on git).

Comment: Thank you guys
I did bind my properties the problem is the properties value don't change but the selected language file is the one that will be changed.
for example:
Title has a value of : MainPage
when its Presented The converter will get The value from the selected resource file that has the name of MainPage if the selected language file is English the value will be "Main Page", but if the selected language file was Arabic the value will be "الصفحة الرئيسية" in that case the value of binding property "Title" did not changed but the selected resource file changed, so it don't update